# Extracting string of dates in a big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have used the below code

```
select --split( INDIVIDUAL_NAMES, '->') as Assigned_to_individual,  

regexp_extract( split( INDIVIDUAL_NAMES, '->'),r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)') from [table name ]where _ID  in('071632')
```

Here we need to extract date and i have given it a try by using d so it gives me numeric fields but this is not giving me complete date.

Comment: It would help a lot to see your input data

Comment: Please give an example value of `INDIVIDUAL_NAMES`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: INDIVIDUAL_NAMES includes Start -> (11/11/2016 08:24:24 AM) -> Akumar (11/11/2016 11:15:33 AM) -> Akumar (01/06/2017 08:08:44 PM) -> Akumar (01/30/2017 10:34:33 AM) -> Akumar (03/15/2017 02:10:12 PM) -> Akumar (03/23/2017 12:42:52 PM) -> Akumar (06/20/2017 12:52:27 PM) -> **(06/27/2017 05:30:48 PM)** -> Sneha Singh (06/28/2017 03:11:34 AM). I would need the date highlighted in bold as this is the first date where no user is assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS ( 
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Start -> (11/11/2016 08:24:24 AM) -> Akumar (11/11/2016 11:15:33 AM) -> Akumar (01/06/2017 08:08:44 PM) -> Akumar (01/30/2017 10:34:33 AM) -> Akumar (03/15/2017 02:10:12 PM) -> Akumar (03/23/2017 12:42:52 PM) -> Akumar (06/20/2017 12:52:27 PM) -> (06/27/2017 05:30:48 PM) -> Sneha Singh (06/28/2017 03:11:34 AM)' AS INDIVIDUAL_NAMES
) 
SELECT 
  id, 
  LTRIM(SPLIT(CONCAT(' ', item), ' (')[OFFSET(0)]) AS name, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M)') AS date_as_string, 
  PARSE_DATETIME('%m/%d/%Y %r', REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M)')) AS date_as_datetime,
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %r', REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M)')) AS date_as_timestamp
FROM yourTable, UNNEST(SPLIT(INDIVIDUAL_NAMES, ' -> ')) AS item 
-- ORDER BY 3
```

above can be slightly simplified to remove redundant portions - for example as

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS ( 
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Start -> (11/11/2016 08:24:24 AM) -> Akumar (11/11/2016 11:15:33 AM) -> Akumar (01/06/2017 08:08:44 PM) -> Akumar (01/30/2017 10:34:33 AM) -> Akumar (03/15/2017 02:10:12 PM) -> Akumar (03/23/2017 12:42:52 PM) -> Akumar (06/20/2017 12:52:27 PM) -> (06/27/2017 05:30:48 PM) -> Sneha Singh (06/28/2017 03:11:34 AM)' AS INDIVIDUAL_NAMES
) 
SELECT 
  id, 
  LTRIM(SPLIT(CONCAT(' ', item), ' (')[OFFSET(0)]) AS name, 
  date_as_string,
  PARSE_DATETIME('%m/%d/%Y %r', date_as_string) AS date_as_datetime,
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %r', date_as_string) AS date_as_timestamp
FROM yourTable, 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(INDIVIDUAL_NAMES, ' -> ')) AS item, 
  UNNEST([REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M)')]) AS date_as_string 
-- ORDER BY 3
```

Output is as below

```sql
id  name        date_as_string          date_as_datetime    date_as_timestamp    
1   Start       null                    null                null     
1   Akumar      01/06/2017 08:08:44 PM  2017-01-06T20:08:44 2017-01-06 20:08:44 UTC
1   Akumar      01/30/2017 10:34:33 AM  2017-01-30T10:34:33 2017-01-30 10:34:33 UTC
1   Akumar      03/15/2017 02:10:12 PM  2017-03-15T14:10:12 2017-03-15 14:10:12 UTC
1   Akumar      03/23/2017 12:42:52 PM  2017-03-23T12:42:52 2017-03-23 12:42:52 UTC
1   Akumar      06/20/2017 12:52:27 PM  2017-06-20T12:52:27 2017-06-20 12:52:27 UTC
1               06/27/2017 05:30:48 PM  2017-06-27T17:30:48 2017-06-27 17:30:48 UTC
1   Sneha Singh 06/28/2017 03:11:34 AM  2017-06-28T03:11:34 2017-06-28 03:11:34 UTC
1               11/11/2016 08:24:24 AM  2016-11-11T08:24:24 2016-11-11 08:24:24 UTC
1   Akumar      11/11/2016 11:15:33 AM  2016-11-11T11:15:33 2016-11-11 11:15:33 UTC
```

> would be really great if you can suggest a similar instance in legacy sql

You can try below for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  id,
  IF(name = CONCAT('(', date_as_string, ')'), '', name) AS name,
  date_as_string
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    NTH(1, SPLIT(item, ' (')) AS name,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M)') AS date_as_string
  FROM FLATTEN((
    SELECT id, SPLIT(INDIVIDUAL_NAMES, ' -> ') AS item, INDIVIDUAL_NAMES
    FROM yourTable 
  ), item)
)
-- ORDER BY date_as_string
```

You can test it with dummy data you provided as below

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  id,
  IF(name = CONCAT('(', date_as_string, ')'), '', name) AS name,
  date_as_string
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    NTH(1, SPLIT(item, ' (')) AS name,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(item, r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M)') AS date_as_string
  FROM FLATTEN((
    SELECT id, SPLIT(INDIVIDUAL_NAMES, ' -> ') AS item, INDIVIDUAL_NAMES
    FROM (
      SELECT 1 AS id, 'Start -> (11/11/2016 08:24:24 AM) -> Akumar (11/11/2016 11:15:33 AM) -> Akumar (01/06/2017 08:08:44 PM) -> Akumar (01/30/2017 10:34:33 AM) -> Akumar (03/15/2017 02:10:12 PM) -> Akumar (03/23/2017 12:42:52 PM) -> Akumar (06/20/2017 12:52:27 PM) -> (06/27/2017 05:30:48 PM) -> Sneha Singh (06/28/2017 03:11:34 AM)' AS INDIVIDUAL_NAMES
    ) AS yourTable 
  ), item)
)
ORDER BY date_as_string
```

Comment: this would be really great if you can suggest a similar instance in legacy sql as the tables we have do not support standard sql. This field is just one of the columns we are fetching whereas with legacy sql we have already built mutiple columns and unfortunately that table does not support standard sql.

Comment: I recommend to move to BigQuery Standard SQL as soon as you can  - meantime see version for Legacy SQL

Comment: this is a life saver, kudos to you

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have access to your table, I used WITH clause to emulate your input table, using the provided input sample. With that, the following query produces the desired output dates. Note that this is a StandardSQL query:

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  input AS (
  SELECT
    "Start -> (11/11/2016 08:24:24 AM) -> Akumar (11/11/2016 11:15:33 AM) -> Akumar (01/06/2017 08:08:44 PM) -> Akumar (01/30/2017 10:34:33 AM) -> Akumar (03/15/2017 02:10:12 PM) -> Akumar (03/23/2017 12:42:52 PM) -> Akumar (06/20/2017 12:52:27 PM) -> (06/27/2017 05:30:48 PM) -> Sneha Singh (06/28/2017 03:11:34 AM)" AS input_group),
  split_output AS (
  SELECT
    SPLIT(input_group, "->") AS output
  FROM
    input)
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(output,r"(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)") AS date
FROM
  split_output so,
  so.output
```

Output (null is for the "Start" entry - note that sql output is not ordered):

```
Row date     
1   03/15/2017 02:10:12  
2   01/06/2017 08:08:44  
3   11/11/2016 08:24:24  
4   06/20/2017 12:52:27  
5   06/28/2017 03:11:34  
6   01/30/2017 10:34:33  
7   06/27/2017 05:30:48  
8   null     
9   11/11/2016 11:15:33  
10  03/23/2017 12:42:52
```